# NULL value in UUID column

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink, uuid

I use EclipseLink + PostgreSQL

I need to create entity with null value of UUID (not primary key) field.

Here is my entity, the field **idUser** must be null in some cases:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "bd00", name = "t_bd00_messages")
public class TBd00Messages implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@Getter @Setter
private UUID id;

@Getter @Setter
private String cdoc;

@Getter @Setter
private String receiver;

@Getter @Setter
private String message;

@Column(name = "status")
@Getter @Setter
private Integer statusCode;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Getter @Setter
private Date tstmp;

@Column(name = "d_send")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Getter @Setter
private Date dSend;

@Column(name = "id_user")
@Getter @Setter
private UUID idUser;

@Getter @Setter
private String subject;
```

And when i persist object, where **idUser = null** - a have an exception:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column     "id_user" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 125
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO bd00.t_bd00_messages (id, CDOC, d_send, id_user, MESSAGE, RECEIVER, status, SUBJECT, TSTMP) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [********, *******, 2016-07-21 14:35:40.858, null, ......
```

Comment: I understand, that null is casting to character varying type, but if i realy need null in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic mappings, EclipseLink will just pass in the null value and let the driver convert, which apparently it cannot do for a UUID null.

To get around this, you will need to tell EclipseLink how to specify the type to the driver, as is shown in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15084881/496099
The key parts are to call

```
Field.setSqlType(Types.OTHER);
Field.setTypeName("uuid");
Field.setColumnDefinition("UUID");
```

on the field used in the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

That would allow you to insert null values into specified column.

```
@Column(name = "id_user", nullable = true)
```

Comment: nullable is default **true**, and with this parameter not working.