# Is there a way to use generated Identity PK (UUID as DEFAULT) using Eclipselink on Postgres 14?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, eclipselink, postgres-14

I have a database running on `postgres` 14 RDBMS. This (relatively) late version has been selected specifically because it features `UUID` `DEFAULT` generation function.

The application that uses the DB is `JAX RS` `java` application running within `Payara` application container using `JPA` `EclipseLink` as its DB layer (ORM). I have configured the application to work with UUIDs as PKs almost without a problem so far as I was only *reading* the entities (that have `UUID` primary keys to be exact).

Recently I am implementing a `POST` endpoint, that is to `INSERT` a record. Now there is a problem with `PK` `id` generation.

The table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE field (                                                            
    id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),                     
    ...                                              
);
```

Until now I had the entity defined like this:

```
@Entity                                                                         
@Converter(name="uuidConverter", converterClass=UUIDEclipseConverter.class)     
@Table(name="field")                                                  
public class Field {                                                   
                                                                                
    @Id                                                                         
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)                         
    @Convert("uuidConverter")                                                   
    @Column(nullable = false)                                                   
    private UUID id;                                                

    ...
```

And it works OK for reading the entites, relating to other entities even the UUIDs work as a part of composite keys of other tables.

But once I tried to insert an entity like this, the query fails. Three different failures for three different generation strategies:

1. `GenerationType.IDENTITY`:

Crashes spectacularly with

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.payara-p1): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: lastval is not yet defined in this session
Error Code: 0
Call: select lastval()
Query: ValueReadQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY" sql="select lastval()")
...
```

- There is no sequence, so the origin of the error is understandable.

2. `GenerationType.TABLE`:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.payara-p1): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "planner.sequence" does not exist
  Position: 8
Error Code: 0
Call: UPDATE planner.SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_TABLE" sql="UPDATE planner.SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
...
```

- Again, expecting a sequence, thus the failure.

3. `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`:
   Without much hope I tried the last option.

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "planner.seq_gen_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 16
Error Code: 0
Call: select nextval('planner.SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE')
...
```

- Understandably a failure occurred.

So I wonder how to achive to utilize the `DEFAULT` generation for a `PK` `ID` the RDBMS provides.

Another approaches I tried so far:

1. I had an idea just to remove the `GeneratedValue` annotation. I must admit it sounded quite promising, but failed, because the Eclipselink doesn't know it should utilize the `DEFAULT` generation the RDBMS provides. And so it tries to `INSERT` `NULL` value into a `NOT NULL` column.
2. Then I tried to set both `insertable` and `updatable` column properties to `false` which also fails, because JPA needs a writable PK identifier.
3. So I removed `updatable` column property and the `INSERT` worked. But the JPA won't hydrate the autogenerated ID into the entity, so I cannot deterministically recognize which record had just been created, so not an ideal solution as well (I also need to return the ID to my API's consumer for it to be able to address the same record later)

For now I am using a workaround based on stripping the `GeneratedValue` annotation and generating random `UUID` at the application side via `PrePersist` listener, which I don't like, but can live with should there be no better solution. Ie:

```
@Entity                                                                         
@Converter(name="uuidConverter", converterClass=UUIDEclipseConverter.class)     
@Table(name="field")                                                            
public class Field {                                                            
                                                                                
    @Id                                                                         
    @Convert("uuidConverter")                                                   
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition="uuid")                          
    private UUID id;                                           

    ...

    @PrePersist                                                                 
    private void prePersist() {                                                 
        if (id != null)                                                         
            return;                                                             
        // TODO: I do not like this solution at all                             
        id = UUID.randomUUID();                                                 
    }                                                                           
}
```

My question therefore is:

Is there a way to configure EclipseLink JPA (via entity annotation?) to utilize a `DEFAULT` value provided for a `PK` column by RDBMS (Posgres 14's `gen_random_uuid()` function specifically) without the need to generate it manually on the application side?

There surely has to be an elegant solution, has it not?

Versions:

- Java openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
- Payara (full) 5.2021.10
- EclipseLink 2.7
- PostgreSQL 14.6

(no hibernate, no spring)

The whole stack is running in a docker environment which DNM IMO.

Comment: In case there is a question about the `UUIDEclipseConverter` - it is a converter ispired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61291101/2915423).

Comment: I switched to a better workaround using [UuidGenerator](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.7/org/eclipse/persistence/annotations/UuidGenerator.html), so I can avoid using `PrePersist` listener. But it is still a workaround as the value is generated on the application side.

Comment: UUIDGenerator that generates one app side is better IMO, as you can pre-allocated sequences independent of the database - so outside the transaction - and not have to obtain them 'after' the insert. Identity didn't work all that well (or at all) with batch inserts on most DBs from what I remember, as lastval only returns the 'last' value generated, not sequence of them. You might look at https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_returninsert.htm which, if you look at how it works for the Oracle platform, might be adapted for Postgres too - or use a stored proc